# Examples of ISO C++ code that is not valid C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++, c++-cli, compatibility

I've seen contradictory answers on the internet with regard to whether C++/CLI is a superset of C++ or not.

The accepted answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179684) claims that "technically no", but doesn't provide an examples of non-C++/CLI code that conforms to ISO C++. Another answer on that question cites a book that says the opposite.

So, can you please provide accurate answers *with example code* that fails on C++/CLI or cite a trusted source (MSDN for example) on this matter?

I had someone this topic come up today and thought I would like to inform myself, but I didn't find any clear answer elsewhere!

Comment: I'm not posting as an answer because I'm not confident about it, but wouldn't something simple like this be an example: `int main() { int gcnew = 5; }` since `gcnew` is a keyword?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Valid C++, invalid C++/CLI:

```
int main()
{
    int gcnew = 42;
}
```

`gcnew`, `generic`, and `nullptr` are all reserved words in C++/CLI; `nullptr` isn't really an issue in C++0x, of course.  Herb Sutter blogged about [C++/CLI keywords: Under the hood](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hsutter/archive/2003/11/23/53519.aspx) in 2003.

For what it's worth, when I was working on a large mixed codebase (both C++ and C++/CLI), I never ran into syntax issues or trivial issues like this.  The giant issue with C++/CLI (in my opinion, of course) is that native code and managed code have completely different resource management paradigms, and it's really easy when writing mixed code to forget which paradigm you need for certain things.  I fixed a lot of errors that were due either to an assumption that managed resources were destroyed deterministically or that native resources would be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks. Good link! I think this is spot on. I wonder whether there are any semantic problems or other parser issues (for ex introduced by the `^` declarator)? Doesn't look like that though.

Comment: @Johannes:  I don't think the `^` or `%` punctuators would be an issue; Objective C also uses `^` (for blocks).  I can't think of anywhere that the compiler could get confused.

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity, does C++/CLI require a `return` statement in `main` by any chance?

Comment: @D.Shawley:  No, just like in C++ you can fall off the end.

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering about the plethora of the super-set/extension polemics. C++/CLI is a **new** language designed to act as a binding between ISO C++ and the ISO CLI. I heartily recommend to read the [C++/CLI Design Rationale](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/C++CLIRationale.pdf)
which clearly states the design goals at the very beginning of the document:

> C++/CLI’s mission is to provide direct
>   access for C++ programmers to use
>   existing CLI libraries and create new
>   ones, with little or no performance
>   overhead, with the minimum amount of
>   extra notation, and with full ISO C++
>   compatibility.