# CLI-c++ references and handles

Tags: .net, reference, c++-cli

im really sorry for this dumb question, is there actual references in .net version of c++? in native c++ there are pointers (`*`, `**`) and references (`&`, `&&`). as far as i know, in cli/c++ there are: interior pointers (i`nterior_ptr<>`), pinning pointers (`pin_ptr<>`), handles (`^`), tracking references (`^%`).

but is there an equivalent for actual native c++ reference?

Comment: What do you expect this C++/CLI-like reference to do?  What do you think the tracking reference does not do that you need some other sort of reference to do?

Comment: well i have read that tracking reference is a reference to a handle, not to an object is it correct?

Comment: it is like pointer to a pointer, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Niello : Tracking references can semantically behave as a reference to a handle _or_ as a reference to an object.

Comment: You can use both pointers and references in C++/CLI, but they are restricted to unmanaged objects.

Comment: thanks guys. i just feel a little bit lost because i cant find any articles on this topic

Comment: Also, note that a tracking reference is only `%`; `^%` is a tracking reference to a handle.

Comment: I think you even got the C++ side of things confused a bit: `**` isn't a primitive, and the apparent connection between `*` and `&` that you try to draw is probably not what you think. In any event, C++/CLI  is a strict superset of C++, so you can continue to do everything that you can do in C++.

Comment: @Kerrek:  It's [almost a strict superset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610671/examples-of-iso-c-code-that-is-not-valid-c-cli).

Comment: @James: haha, pedant :-) Fair point though!

Comment: isnt (**) a pointer to a pointer? for example when you pass a pointer to a function and dont want it to be altered, you pass pointer to that pointer instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++/CLI supports regular pointers and references just like C++ does.  But not to objects of a managed class.  That cannot work by design, managed objects get moved in memory when the garbage collector compacts the heap.  This is checked well at compile time, the compiler will tell you when you get it wrong.  Managed pointer and reference syntax is ^ and %.  You can convert a managed pointer to an unmanaged one with the pin_ptr<> class.  Whose side-effect is that the object gets pinned so it cannot be moved and invalidate the pointer.

Terms like 'tracking reference' and 'reference to a handle' are a useful semantic description of a managed pointer.  It doesn't otherwise have anything to do with what happens at runtime.  They are regular pointers just like C++ pointers and have the same perf.  There is no intermediary 'handle'.  The only difference is that the garbage collector can find them back and update their value.